# Generalized linear model in R; what family to use?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I'm trying to find out which family I need to use for a generalized linear model in R where the  outcome is continuous (Biotic indices like Shannon and water framework directive water quality measures) and the predictors are counts (families and feeding habits).

I found info for the other way around, but not for this scenario. I've been going through literature but cannot find the answer.

If it was the other way around, according to this https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/glm.html I should use Poisson.

Also tried to scan this document, but no answer: https://www.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/upm-binaries/21121_Chapter_15.pdf

Histogram of DV:

[image: histogram]

Comment: You say your outcome is continuous, that alone determines the family. But how continuous is your DV? Is it bounded?

Comment: @user2974951 Shannon is "Rarely greater than 4", some indices are actually scores from 0-1 with unlimited decimal places, and some are natural numbers that are theoretically without bounds but in my data don't exceed 100.

Comment: Can you post a histogram of your DV in your question?

Comment: @user2974951 Edited question. I guess this is what you mean with DV?

Comment: Yes, dependent variable DV = outcome, the plot that you posted is far from normal, so you will have to think of something else. It is also not Poisson distributed. A fractional logistic regression maybe.

Comment: @user2974951 Ah, ok. Yes, I know it probably wasn't Poisson, the predictors all are Poisson distributed though as they are count data.

I'll look into your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just a normal distribution? There's no indication here that you need anything different. Your dependent variable is continuous and unbounded, so there's no need for Poisson, logistic, etc.

Comment: Also, the DV does not have to be normal to use the Gaussian family. It assumes the residuals are normal. The DV does have to be continuous or close to it.

Comment: @mkt Yes, I have. Only one of the tests the residuals did not come back as normally distributed. That's the reason for trying to explore further.

Comment: Linear models are robust to small deviations from some of the assumptions. If you're concerned about it, you could ask a new question with the figure that you're concerned about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no indication here that you need anything other than a normal distribution. It's possible, but none of the information you present supports that. Your dependent variable is continuous and unbounded, so there's no need for Poisson, logistic, etc.